# SQL comparsion/synchronization speed

Tags: c#, sql

I have two datatables let's just call them `db1` and `db2`. `db2` contains all the records `db1` has but `db1` doesn't contain all the records of `db2` (they both have the same columns). I have to check the modifications every day in `db1` and apply the same for `db2`.

- Currently my tool "exports" both tables into `DataTables`, performs the conversion and updates/imports the records into `db2`:

`SELECT * FROM db1` -> `db1_table`

`SELECT * FROM db2` -> `db2_table`

```
for (int i = 0; i < db1_table.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < db2_table.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                //if db1_table.Rows[i] != db2_table.Rows[j] -> UPDATE db2 SET etc.
                //if db1_table.Rows[i] doesn't exist in db2 -> INSERT INTO db2 etc.
            }
    }
```

This version becomes quite slow after a while. I'm talking about tens of thousands of records.

- The other was my initial idea but I found it slow. I pull the whole db1, loop through all of its records and execute an sql query each time:

`SELECT * FROM db1` -> `db1_table`

```
for (int i = 0; i < db1_table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            //SELECT * FROM db2 WHERE "attributes LIKE db1_table.Rows[i]
            //do the comparsion here and execute the UPDATE/INSERT commands if necessary
        }
```

Which is the faster(better) way? Are there any other option I might have?

Comment: It's complicated. db1 is not mine, I have only read access and the owner doesn't want my users to load his db through my application, therefore I have to use my own.

Comment: if it is SQL server check [this SO QnA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425651/how-to-synchronize-databases-in-different-servers-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: These datatables are in different databases, in different locations so I believe I won't be able to export the whole table each time I want to synchronize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Side note: you really shouldn't store duplicate data in two tables with the same structure in the first place...

Side note: you should be doing this update in SQL.

To answer your actual question. What you're experiencing is an O(N^2) algorithmic complexity. It can be reduced to around O(N) if you build a hashtable (dictionary) of one of the tables, and you only iterate on the other one. When you look for a match, then you look in the hashtable instead of iteration, that's around O(1) instead of O(N). You just need a good key value that you use for hashing.

Something like this:

```
var dict = db2_table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToDictionary(row2 => row2["keycolumn"].Value); // this is the hashing, make sure no duplicate keys exist!
foreach (DataRow row1 in db1_table.Rows) {
    DataRow row2;
    if (dict.TryGetValue(row1["keycolumn"].Value, out row2)) {
        // row1 and row2 match by the key column, do something with them
        dict.Remove(row2["keycolumn"].Value);
    }
    // else no match, row1 must be a new row
}
// now dict contains the keys from db2 which have no match in db1, they must have been deleted
```

Comment: I have a good key value, but how that hashtable should look alike?

Comment: `Dictionary<typeofkey, DataRow>`. Write one iteration where you put all of db1 into the dictionary, then iterate over db2.

Comment: And why would this be faster than the original one? I'm using the db1_table exactly like a hashtable.

Comment: No, you are iterating over db1 rows, that takes N steps (N=number of rows), and every time you add new rows, it is getting slower. In a hashtable, you get a match in 1 step. This is a huge speedup.

Comment: OK. So if I have the hashtable of db1, and I'm iterating through db2 how can I check whether it exists in the hastable, and if yes compare the values of the DataRow?

Comment: Thanks a lot. One last Q, promise :) Shall I use the `ContainsKey()` method as well each time? As if there is no match I have to insert that specific row to the other db.

Comment: `TryGetValue` returns false if the key doesn't exist.

Comment: The only problem with this is that can't detect rows in db1 that have been deleted.

Comment: "It can't detect" is too strong, it can, I just didn't write it that way, you didn't say there can be deletions in table 1. But now I edited it, and now it does that too. I switched handling of tables 1 and 2, I added one Remove call, and in the end you get a list of deleted records.

Answer (score 0):

There's another option that's O(n) if you have a unique ID that you can order on and compare: Order both tables by the ID and walk them both at once, generating lists of pending changes.  After that you can apply the pending changes.  The reason for generating lists of changes is so that you can batch commands together at the end of the change detection and benefit from things like bulk inserts, CTEs or temp tables to join on for deletes, and batched command groups for updates -- all of which reduce one of the biggest sources of latency in this kind of operation: DB round trips.

The main loop looks like the following:

```
// Assuming that IDs are long.  Change as required.
long db1_id;
long db2_id;
var idsToAppend = new List<long>();
var idsToUpdate = new List<long>();
var idsToDelete = new List<long>();
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
while (i < db1_table.Rows.Count && j < db2_table.Rows.Count) {
    db1_id = db1_table.Rows[i]["ID"];
    db2_id = db2_table.Rows[j]["ID"];
    if (i == db1_table.Rows.Count && j < db2_table.Rows.Count) {
        // There's extra rows in the destination that have been removed from the source
        idsToDelete.Add(db1_id);
        j++;
    } else if (j < db1_table.Rows.Count && j == db2_table.Rows.Count) {
        // There's extra rows in the source that need added to the destination
        idsToAppend.Add(db1_id);
        i++;
    } else if (db1_id == db2_id) {
        // On the same ID in both datasets
        if !(db1_table.Rows[i] == db2_table.Rows[j]) {
            // I know == won't work -- only do this if db1 may change and the changes must be propagated to db2
            idsToUpdate.Add(db1_id);
        }
        i++;
        j++;
    } else if (db1_id > db2_id) {
        // row in db1 was removed, remove row in db2
        idsToDelete.Add(db1_id);
        j++;
    } else {
        // implicit: db1_id < db2_id
        // implicit: row in db1 doesn't exist in db2, needs added
        idsToAppend(db1_id);
        i++;
    }
}
// Walk idsToAppend, idsToUpdate, and idsToDelete applying changes
```