# How to overcome data mismatch on several database

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, architecture, system

In my system I have **more than one project**, each project connect with individual DB .When Insert transaction occur in any project then record insert on all of the db,but when update event occur in any project then respective update occur only it’s  DB not impact rest of the project db.it’s my system process.After continue this process data become difference on each db.With out change this process  what I do to overcome this data  mismatch problem.

**Suppose** on system-1 transaction activity :

Transaction -->Update  -->Modification occur only on system1 db not in system-2,sytem-3 db

[image]

Any type of suggestion will be acceptable,if have any query please ask,thanks in advanced.

Comment: Please explain more what you mean by "but when update event occur in any project then respective update occur only it’s DB not impact rest of the project db".  It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Joel Lee thanks for you comment please ,check the modification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently working in almost the same Project architecture. Our solution is to create [Orchestration module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orchestration_(computing)) that will manage Single_entry_point module. Last one is responsible to unify the information from the *Upstream* (cluster of different DataBases and Service systems) and after it to upload/distribute it to a *Downstream* (Single_Data_Warehouse). By doing so - you can guarantee that all your information is actual in every moment. The *Orchestrator* communicates with Service massages when dealing with all other modules.

This design is based on [Pipes and Filters Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568100.aspx) concept.

[image]

I think that in your case, you can only add logic for *Update DB information* and reuse all that you have at this point. If you spend some time on such Single_entry_point module, which to deal with not only *Insert*, but with *Transaction Update* too.

When it comes to Databases *“eyeballing”* validation (done by SQL scripting) you definatelly have to consider the use of [Informatica](http://www.informatica.com/us/etl-testing/#fbid=lPRq7zjlpUY). To be more specific - when data as it is being moved into production systems. The data in your production systems has to be right in order to support your business decision making.  Informatica Data Validation Option provides the ETL testing automation and management capabilities to ensure that your production systems are not compromised by the *data update process*.

If you find that this options doesn't suits your needs, here are resources I found about this topic:

- [database-synchronization-an-overview-of-approaches](http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/7720/~/database-synchronization---an-overview-of-approaches)
- [MSDN Synchronizing Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726002(v=sql.110).aspx)
- [how-to-synchronize-databases-in-different-servers-in-sql-server-2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425651/how-to-synchronize-databases-in-different-servers-in-sql-server-2008)
- [sql-comparison-sdk-synchronizing-databases](http://assets.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-comparison-sdk/sql-comparison-sdk-synchronizing-databases.pdf)